# BizTalk 2006 duplicating SOAP Send Port

Tags: duplicates, biztalk, port, send

In one orchestration, I've got a static response SOAP Send Port configured. I would like to be able the same message to another Web Service. I've thought about Send Port Group but my Static SOAP Send Prot doesn't appear in the listbox.
Does anyone know how to achieve that ?

Comment: You want to send a message to more than 1 web service?  Create another send port that subscribes to the message.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is send the same message to more than 1 web service, create another soap send port that subscribes to the message.